# ggplot2 geom_tile diagonal line overlay

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm looking for a way to produce a diagonal slash from the bottom left the to top right corner of a cell within a plot made using `geom_tile`.

The input is a melted data frame with two categorical factor columns, **sample** and **gene**. I'd like to use something like `geom_segment`, but I'm not able to specify fractional increments. Any ideas on the best way to accomplish this?

edit: Here is a reproducible example, I can't share one from my own data, as it's protected patient information.

```
df <- data_frame( gene     = c('TP53','TP53','MTOR','BRACA1'),
                  sample   = c('A','B','A','B'),
                  diagonal = c(FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE),
                  effect   = c('missense', 'nonsense', 'missense', 'silent') )

 ggplot(df, aes(sample, gene)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = effect))
```

[image: example no diagonal]

what I'm looking for:

[image: example no diagonal]

Comment: This is an interesting question, I'd upvote if you'd share a little data via simulation or `dput()` to make [a nice reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061).

Comment: Are you sure you just want to draw a diagonal line? The variable names/levels suggest that you actually want to draw `SplitTile`s as provided by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77202559/1870254) of mine. (One half-tile for each of the two alleles a diploid genome has)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(
  x = rep(c(2, 5, 7, 9, 12), 2),
  y = rep(c(1, 2), each = 5),
  z = factor(1:10),
  w = rep(diff(c(0, 4, 6, 8, 10, 14)), 2)
)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = z))
gb <- ggplot_build(p)
p + geom_segment(data=gb$data[[1]][1:2, ], 
                 aes(x=xmin, xend=xmax, y=ymin, yend=ymax), 
                 color="white")
```

[image]

---

In your example, could also rely on the indices of the factor levels like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame( gene     = c('TP53','TP53','MTOR','BRACA1'),
                  sample   = c('A','B','A','B'),
                  diagonal = c(FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE),
                  effect   = c('missense', 'nonsense', 'missense', 'silent') )
df$cross <- c(F,T,T,F)
ggplot(df, aes(sample, gene)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = effect)) + 
  geom_segment(data=transform(subset(df, !!cross), sample=as.numeric(sample), gene=as.numeric(gene)), 
               aes(x=sample-.49, xend=sample+.49, y=gene-.49, yend=gene+.49), 
               color="white", size=2)
```

(Note that I used `data.frame` and not `dplyr::data_frame`, so that both columns become factors.)

[image]

If you want a legend:

```
ggplot(df, aes(sample, gene)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = effect)) + 
  geom_segment(data=transform(subset(df, !!cross), sample=as.numeric(sample), gene=as.numeric(gene)), 
               aes(x=sample-.49, xend=sample+.49, y=gene-.49, yend=gene+.49, color=cross), 
               size=2) + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c("TRUE"="white", "FALSE"=NA))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. It's not quite as robust as I'd like, since the grob object is subject to change based on the plot context. I've upvoted, but I'd like to see if I can solicit something a bit more straightforward if possible.

Comment: You're welcome. I the example, I just read from the grob object, where each tile starts and ends. I agree it's not very elegant. In your case, you could also use the indices of the factor levels. See my edit.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you so much! I was trying to do this with factor levels and couldn't quite get it. Great solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `geom_abline`.  You can tweak `intercept` and `slope` to get what you want. More info and examples [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_abline.html).

```
ggplot(df, aes(sample, gene)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = effect)) +
  geom_abline(intercept = 1, slope = 1, color="white", size=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't actually want specific lines, but just want to highlight, you can simply draw dots:

```
ggplot(df, aes(sample, gene)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = effect)) +
    geom_point(aes(sample, gene))
```

You can make it *look like* a line: `geom_point(aes(sample, gene), shape='/', size=10, color='white')`

To have the lines be only on some tiles, simply pass only the rows with those coordinates to `geom_point`: `geom_point(data=filter(df, diagonal), aes(sample, gene))`

Alternatively, you can hack it with a manual shape scale: `geom_point(aes(sample, gene, shape=diagonal)) + scale_shape_manual(values=c(' ', '/'))`