# Split overlapping tiles by facet in geom_tile

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-tile

I have stacked a data frame which shows `value`s per `id` across `group`s:

```r
df <- tibble::tibble(id = c(LETTERS[1:6], LETTERS[1:5]),
                     value = c(paste0("V", 1:6), paste0("V", 1:5)),
                     group = c(rep("group_1", 6), rep("group_2", 5)))

df
#> # A tibble: 11 x 3
#>    id    value group  
#>    <chr> <chr> <chr>  
#>  1 A     V1    group_1
#>  2 B     V2    group_1
#>  3 C     V3    group_1
#>  4 D     V4    group_1
#>  5 E     V5    group_1
#>  6 F     V6    group_1
#>  7 A     V1    group_2
#>  8 B     V2    group_2
#>  9 C     V3    group_2
#> 10 D     V4    group_2
#> 11 E     V5    group_2
```

I want to create a heatmap showing the "availability" of each `value` (x) for each `id` (y) across `group`s (fill):

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = id, y = value, fill = group)) + 
  geom_tile()
```

[image]

The problem is that the `fill` overlaps: All I can see is that F/V6 is only in `group_1` (and not in `group_2`). However, for IDs A to E, values V1 to V5 are available in **both** groups, and thus the color of `group_2` is on top of `group_1`, making it look like they are only available in `group_2`.

If I use `facet_wrap()`, the availability is more obvious:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = id, y = value, fill = group)) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  facet_wrap("group")
```

[image]

However, in my real setting, the heatmap is very large so it is difficult to compare which values are available in which group.

Is it possible to split each tile in half if the value is available in both groups and keep it full if it is only present in one group? So in the first plot above, the blue tiles would be split in half (showing both blue and red), and the red tile would remain as is.

---

### UPDATE

Thanks for stefan's excellent hint on using `position = "dodge"`. However, I noticed that my problem is actually a bit more complex than my reprex above: Each `value` may appear in multiple `id`s per `group`. When using `position = "dodge"`, ggplot2 then "divides" each `id` "column" in as many parts as there are occurrences of each `value` within this `id`:

```r
df <- tibble::tibble(id = c("A", "A",  "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"),
                     value = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V1", "V3", "V1", "V2", "V4", "V1", "V2", "V1", "V3", "V1", "V4"),
                     group = c(rep("group_1", 8), rep("group_2", 6)))

df
#> # A tibble: 14 x 3
#>    id    value group  
#>    <chr> <chr> <chr>  
#>  1 A     V1    group_1
#>  2 A     V2    group_1
#>  3 A     V3    group_1
#>  4 B     V1    group_1
#>  5 B     V3    group_1
#>  6 C     V1    group_1
#>  7 C     V2    group_1
#>  8 C     V4    group_1
#>  9 A     V1    group_2
#> 10 A     V2    group_2
#> 11 B     V1    group_2
#> 12 B     V3    group_2
#> 13 C     V1    group_2
#> 14 C     V4    group_2

ggplot(df, aes(x = id, y = value, fill = group)) + 
  geom_tile(position = "dodge")
```

You can see that in "column A" the three tiles are placed both above and next to each other, splitting the available space in three. What I want to achieve is plotting these three pairs of tiles in "column A" on top of each other so they are aligned, using the whole available space alloted to "column A" for each value.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to use `position="dodge"`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = id, y = value, fill = group)) + 
  geom_tile(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

---

## UPDATE

You could try by mapping group on the `group` aes:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = id, y = value, fill = group, group = group)) + 
  geom_tile(position = "dodge", color = "black") # adding 'color' for borders
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've upvoted your answer, but haven't "accepted" it yet, as I noticed that my problem is actually a bit more complex than my initial reprex. Apologies for the vagueness. I've updated my question accordingly. Any ideas on how to solve my actual problem as well?

Comment: @lks_swrx Not 100% sure about your desired result. But you could try by mapping `group` on the `group` aes, i..e `ggplot(df, aes(x = id, y = value, fill = group, group = group))`.

Comment: Perfect, adding `group = group` actually did the trick. Exactly what I wanted, many thanks! I added the solution to your answer so other users can see it more clearly.

Answer (score 3):

If you want triangles, think you'll probably need to do it manually using some wrangling and `geom_polygon`, something like:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- tibble::tibble(x = c(LETTERS[1:6], LETTERS[1:5]),
                     y = c(paste0("V", 1:6), paste0("V", 1:5)),
                     group = c(rep("group_1", 6), rep("group_2", 5)))

df1    <- df[!duplicated(interaction(df$x, df$y)),]
df2    <- df[duplicated(interaction(df$x, df$y)),]
df2    <- df[rep(seq(nrow(df)), each = 3),]
df2$x1 <- as.numeric(as.factor(df2$x))
df2$y1 <- as.numeric(as.factor(df2$y))
df2$x1 <- df2$x1 + c(-0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
df2$y1 <- df2$y1 + c(-0.5, -0.5, 0.5)
df2$z  <- rep(seq(nrow(df2)/3), each = 3)

ggplot(df1, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = group)) + 
  geom_tile() +
  geom_polygon(data = df2, aes(x = x1, y = y1, group = z))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I just implemented a new geom `GeomSplitTile` that allows to plot two related values in each field of a matrix plot. Apart from adding the required definitions, this is much easier to use and should allow for arbitrary combination with faceting and `position`s:

```r
library(rlang)
library(ggplot2)


# Provides a diagonally split version of GeomTile
# by [jan-glx](https://github.com/jan-glx), based on ggplot2::GeomTile by the [ggplot2 authors](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/graphs/contributors)

draw_key_split_tile <- function(data, params, size) {
  
  data$width <- data$width %||% params$width %||% 1
  data$height <- data$height %||% params$height %||% 1
  data$width[is.na(data$width)] <- 1
  data$height[is.na(data$height)] <- 1
  if (isTRUE(data$split)) {
    x <- c(0, 1, 0)
    y <- c(0, 1, 1)
  } else {
    x <- c(0, 1, 1)
    y <- c(0, 1, 0)
  }
  x <- 0.5 + (x-0.5) * data$width
  y <- 0.5 + (y-0.5) * data$height
  
  grid::polygonGrob(
    x = x,
    y = y,
    default.units = "npc",
    gp = grid::gpar(
      col = data$colour,
      fill = alpha(data$fill, data$alpha)
    )
  )
}

geom_split_tile <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL,
                            stat = "identity", position = "identity",
                            ...,
                            linejoin = "mitre",
                            na.rm = FALSE,
                            show.legend = NA,
                            inherit.aes = TRUE) {
  layer(
    data = data,
    mapping = mapping,
    stat = stat,
    geom = GeomSplitTile,
    position = position,
    show.legend = show.legend,
    inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = rlang:::list2(
      linejoin = linejoin,
      na.rm = na.rm,
      ...
    )
  )
}

GeomSplitTile <- ggproto(
  "GeomSplitTile", GeomPolygon,
  extra_params = c("na.rm"),
  
  setup_data = function(data, params) {
    data$width <- data$width %||% params$width %||% resolution(data$x, FALSE)
    data$height <- data$height %||% params$height %||% resolution(data$y, FALSE)
    data$split <- as.factor(data$split %||% params$split %||% FALSE)
    
    K = 3
    n <- nrow(data)
    new_data <- data.frame(
      x = rep(data$x, each=K) + rep(3-as.integer(data$split)*2, each=K) * rep(c(-1,  1, 1), n) * rep(data$width / 2, each=K),
      y = rep(data$y, each=K) + rep(3-as.integer(data$split)*2, each=K) * rep(c(-1, -1, 1), n) * rep(data$height / 3, each=K),
      group = rep(seq_len(n), each=K)
    )
    new_data <- cbind(new_data, data[rep(seq_len(n), each = K), setdiff(colnames(data), c("x", "y", "group")), drop = FALSE])
    new_data
  },
  
  default_aes = aes(fill = "grey20", colour = NA, linewidth = 0.1, linetype = 1,
                    alpha = NA, width = NA, height = NA),
  
  required_aes = c("x", "y", "split"),
  
  draw_key = draw_key_split_tile
)

scale_split <- function(..., scale_name="scale_direction", palette = function(n) if(n>2) error(paste0(scale_name, " can handle at most 2 levels")) else c(FALSE, TRUE)) discrete_scale(aesthetics = "split", scale_name=scale_name, palette = palette, ... )
```

Use with your axample:

```r
df <- tibble::tibble(id = c(LETTERS[1:6], LETTERS[1:5]),
                     value = c(paste0("V", 1:6), paste0("V", 1:5)),
                     group = c(rep("group_1", 6), rep("group_2", 5)))

ggplot(df, aes(x = id, y = value, fill = group, split=group)) + 
  geom_split_tile() + scale_split()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-09-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Hope this helps, let me know if you would like to this this in a standalone / some other R package!